# How to had try exception to log to logger using python

Tags: python

I have a Scenario where i want to check file exist at path or not

But if file not exist at path `catch the error` and log it to file using logging module and then script should break (exit). further code of lines should not be executed which is next function addtion_value if first function falls

**Note :** my script file contains lots of function one after the other in same file

**Below is my code , i was able to code but with error**

```
import path 
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt',level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)',filemode='w')

def checkfileexist(Pth,Fle):
    var=Path(Pth+'/'+Fle)
    try :
        if var.is_file():
            logging.INFO('File  found')
            return (var)
    exception Nofile as er:
        logging.error('Not Found file')
    else:
        sys.exit()
   
def additionvalue(a,b):
    return (a+b)
```

Is it possible to make use of import os module and create code ?

Comment: use logging.info not logging.INFO

Comment: Also, `exception Nofile as er:` needs to be `exception Nofile as er:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your script and it's working

```
import os
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt',level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s- %(message)s',filemode='a')

def checkfileexist(Pth,Fle):
    var=Pth+'/'+Fle
    try :
        if (var is None):
            logging.error('Path is empty')
            raise Exception("empty path")
        if os.path.exists(var):
            logging.error('File  found')
            return (var)
        else:
            raise Exception("File Not found")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Not Found file')
        sys.exit()

   
def additionvalue(a,b):
    return (a+b)
```

- you were not logging the message `%(asctime)s- %(message)s` as well as instead of 'w' you should use 'a' (append)

Comment: : in the above code itself , is it possible to check how many argument passed , if i dont pass any argument where in that case does it catch error and display for example : checkfileexist('/d/demo/','') or checkfileexist()

Comment: ya , we can do that by adding one more condition

Comment: : How to do that can you demonstrate in  your same code , will test and upvote

Comment: I have added the condition in the code, so it will check if the path is empty or not and then will move forward

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without raising any error:

```py
def checkfileexist(Pth,Fle):
    var = Path(Pth+'/'+Fle)
    if var.is_file():
        logging.info('File  found')
        return var
    else:
        logging.error('Not Found file')
```

But if you insist, you can do something like this:

```py
def checkfileexist(Pth,Fle):
    var = Path(Pth+'/'+Fle)
    try:
        if not var.is_file():
            raise FileNotFoundError()
 
    except FileNotFoundError as er:
        logging.error('Not Found file')

    else:
        logging.info('File  found')
        return var
```

---

> need to check both the parameter is passed to the function `checkfilexist()`

When you define a function with required parameters (as the function above), Python will already raise an error if you don't pass all its parameters:

```
checkfileexist()
# Raises TypeError: checkfileexist() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Pth' and 'Fle'

checkfileexist('/c/d/',)
# Raises TypeError: checkfileexist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Fle'
```

For the third case (raise an error if any argument is empty), you can do something like this:

```py
def checkfileexist(Pth,Fle):
    # Same as `if len(Pth) == 0:`
    if not Pth:
        raise TypeError("parameter Pth must not be empty")

    # Same as `if len(Fle) == 0:`
    if not Fle:
        raise TypeError("parameter Fle must not be empty")

    # ...
```

Comment: in the above code itself , is it possible to check how many argument passed , if i dont pass any argument where in that case does it catch error and display  for example : `checkfileexist('/d/demo/','')`  or `checkfileexist()`

Comment: Do you want the code to raise a FileNotFoundError if the user doesn't pass any arguments to `checkfilexists`?

Comment: need to check both the parameter is passed to the function `checkfilexist()`  : rasie error  and `checkfileexist('/c/d/',) `or `checkfileexist('','')` this all case it should raise error

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if this solves your problem.

Comment: can you consolidate in the above code the below Type error code

Comment: Why you have not made use of `if Pth is None`  or `Pth =='' :`  instead of `len(Pth) == 0: `

Answer (score 0):

After all above answers and tried on my editor and prepared this below script

Correct me if any thing wrong in below code

Thanks for helping me with your approach: @[lakshika-parihar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13890216/lakshika-parihar) @[enzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9997212/enzo) & @[Joaquim Procopio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15193272/joaquim-procopio)

But this worked for me

```
import os
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL\\log.txt', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s : %(message)s', filemode='w')

def checkfileexist(file_path, file_name):
    try:
        var_pth = str(file_path)
        var_fle = str(file_name)
        var_full = var_pth + var_fle

        if var_pth is None or var_pth == '':
            logging.error("Path parameter is empty")
            raise TypeError('Path parameter is empty')
        else:
            pass
            logging.info(f'Path : {var_pth}')

        if var_fle is not None and var_fle != '':
            pass
            logging.info(f'Full : {var_fle}')
        else:
            logging.error("File parameter is empty")
            raise TypeError('File parameter is empty')

        if os.path.exists(var_full):
            logging.error(f'File : {var_fle} is found at path : {var_pth} ')
            logging.info(f'File : {var_full}')
            return var_full

    except:
        logging.error(f"ERRO : {erron} ")
        sys.exit()

try:
    #  Calling function
    #  checkfileexist('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL\\', 'ABX')
    #  checkfileexist('', 'ABX')   #Output : 2021-07-28 22:45:48,307 : Path parameter is empty
    #  checkfileexist('', '')      #Output : 2021-07-28 22:46:53,758 : Path parameter is empty
    checkfileexist()               #2021-07-29 11:12:46,207 : ERROR : checkfileexist() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'file_path' and 'file_name'

except Exception as er:
    logging.error(f"ERROR : {er} ")
    sys.exit()
```