# How to count number of parameters passed to a function?

Tags: python

I am not getting how to fetch error details to file , it is printing zero byte file when no parameter passed to function: `checkfileexist()`

Is there any way to check, if the function should take 2 parameters, `file_path` and `file_name` that the the argument count passed is 2 and if not log the error details to log file using logging?

I have taken reference of previously raised question and below code is created. Previously raised question: [How to had try exception to log to logger using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68563333/how-to-had-try-exception-to-log-to-logger-using-python/68563418#comment121172774_68563418)

**My code :**

```
import os
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL\\log.txt', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s : %(message)s', filemode='w')


def checkfileexist(file_path, file_name):
    try:
        var_pth = str(file_path)
        var_fle = str(file_name)
        var_full = var_pth + var_fle

        if not var_pth and not var_fle:
            logging.error(f"Both parameter is not passed : Parameter 1 : {var_pth} : Parameter 2 : {var_fle}")
            raise TypeError('Both parameter is not passed', var_pth, var_fle)
        else:
            pass
            logging.info(f"Both parameter is passed : Parameter 1 : {var_pth} : Parameter 2 : {var_fle}")

        if var_pth is None or var_pth == '' or len(var_pth) == 0:
            logging.error("Path parameter is empty")
            raise TypeError('Path parameter is empty')
        else:
            pass
            logging.info(f'Path : {var_pth}')

        if var_fle is None or var_fle == '' or len(var_fle) == 0:
            logging.error("File parameter is empty")
            raise TypeError('File parameter is empty')
        else:
            pass
            logging.info(f'Full : {var_fle}')

        if os.path.exists(var_full):
            logging.error(f'File : {var_fle} is found at path : {var_pth} ')
            logging.info(f'File : {var_full}')
            return var_full

    except:
        sys.exit()


# Calling function
checkfileexist()
```

Comment: You can just catch the error raised by the bad function call. Normally you wouldn't catch that exception though. When using non-vararg positional arguments, passing the wrong number of arguments is an error in the code that should be fixed, not anticipated and logged.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the Exception like this:

```py
try:
    checkfileexist()
except TypeError:
    sys.exit(1) #or log it
```

But it does not make much sense to catch this as you should fix your code to pass on the correct number of arguments.